Link budget with transmitter duty cycle (satellite earth station to a 5G terrestrial receiver)
I want to calculate link budget in a communications link where transmitter is a small satellite earth station and victim is a 5G base station. The question that I have is whether we can account for the earth station duty cycle in the link budget. In radar systems, we can say that

EIRP (duty cycle) = Peak Power + Gain + 10log(duty cycle)

where the parameters peak power and gain are the conducted power and antenna gain of the radar system as a transmitter. Can we do the same for a satellite earth station that operates with small duty cycle? Doing so produces a negative term 10log(duty cycle) which reduces interference.

“Doing so produces a negative term 10log(duty cycle)…” yep, that’s correct. “…which reduces interference” what exactly do you mean by that?

Yes, that’s a valid way to incorporate small duty cycles into your link budget.

This depends strongly on the definition of Interference by the victim system, or the regulations that apply.
For example in regular EMC calculations, CISPR-22 specifies a quasi-peak detector with an attack time of 1 ms, a decay time 550 ms and an IF filter bandwidth of 120 kHz.
So using this filter spec, if your ground station duty cycle is 1%, this might mean:

that it transmits continously for 12 minutes per day, and is silent for the rest of the time. In this case the peak power would be applicable of course.
or that it transmits a pulse of 100 us, once every 10 ms, in which case it will be averaged out by the filter, and the power including the duty cycle will apply.

No doubt the 5G station, or failing that the normal IEC/FCC regulations in that country, have their own definition of interference, possibly including narrow and wide band signals, duty cycle, etc.
It seems likely that unless your system has a very wide bandwidth, or a pulse time much shorter than a 5G symbol, that the peak power would be the correct figure to use. i.e. the duty cycle is irrelevent in the interference link budget calculation.
